# Lie algebra homomorphism: is my understanding correct?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Using answer to my previous question I made some progress towards understanding Lie algebra homomorphisms. But of course I am unsure whether my thoughts are really correct so again I'd like to request the community to check my thoughts.

> Is the following correct?

It is my goal to find a Lie algebra isomorphism from the Lie algebra of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ to the Lie algebra of $O(3, \mathbb C)$.

The group $G = SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is both connected and simply connected. The following is a theorem (it can be found e.g. [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~mduchin/womp/lie.pdf)):

For Lie groups $G, H$ with $G$ connected and simply connected,
a linear map $\varphi : \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak h$ is the derivative of a homomorphism $\phi  : G \to H$ if and only if φ is a Lie algebra homomorphism.

Hence if $\phi: SL_2 \to O(3,\mathbb C)$ is  a Lie group homomorphism, its derivative will yield a Lie group homomorphism.

> (If $\phi: SL_2 \to O(3,\mathbb C)$ is a Lie group isomorphism is its
>   derivative a Lie algebra isomorphism?)

Therefore, to find the desired Lie algerba isomorphism I pick  <s>a basis</s> generators for $SL_2$ and  <s>a basis</s>  generators for $O(3, \mathbb C)$, define a map on the generators and then take its derivative.

<s>But the derivative of a linear map is the linear map itself here. This leads me to believe that I made a mistake somewhere. Or did I not?</s>

**Edit**

In response to Ben's comment: Let's replace "basis" with "generators" instead.

Comment: Lie groups are not linear spaces, so the group homomorphism will not be a linear map. The phrase "pick a basis for $SL_2$" doesn't make sense because $SL_2$ isn't a linear space.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Oops, of course. You are right. What if I replace "basis" with "generators"? It's not yet obvious to me at this moment how to take a derivative of a group homomorphism though...

Comment: $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is not finitely generated as a group, and even if it were generators aren't as nice as basis elements of a vector space.  Generators can have relations which need to be respected by their images in the group you're mapping to.

Comment: @Jim Thank you, I did not know this. So... is it not possible to specify a group homomorphism?

Comment: Sure it is, you can just use the matrix coordinates to do it.

Comment: For example $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}\right] \mapsto \left[\begin{smallmatrix} d & -c \\ -b & a \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ specifies a homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C) \to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: @Jim Right but I probably need an isomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb C) \to O(3, \mathbb C)$ so that when I take the derivative I get a Lie algebra isomorphism. (all assuming that what I suggest in the question is actually correct)

Comment: Yes, I was just giving you an example of how you specify a homomorphism without using generators.

Comment: You need a group homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow O(3,\mathbb{C})$. It does not have to be an isomorphism (and as Jim mentions below, it can't be, since the groups are not isomorphic). What it does have to be is *locally* a homeomorphism of the underlying topological spaces. Then the derivative at the origin will be an isomorphism of Lie algebras.

Comment: If you want to specify a map on generators, $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is generated by matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\ &1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1& \\y&1\end{pmatrix}$. However, to @Jim's point, it may be hard to verify that a map specified on these generators is a homomorphism, because you'd have to check somehow that relations satisfied by the generators in $SL_2$ are also satisfied by their images in $O(3,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @learner I just noticed that everything I said below, commenting on Jim's answer, was said by Qiaochu in his answer to your other question. I can explain what he's doing with enough detail and concreteness to write down the isomorphism explicitly. Let me know if I should.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing Lie groups with Lie algebras.  The Lie group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is
$$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \ \middle| \ a, b, c, d \in \mathbb C \ \text{and} \ ad - bc = 1\right\}$$
and it's Lie algebra is
$$\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & -a \end{bmatrix} \ \middle| \ a, b, c \in \mathbb C\right\}$$
Lie algebras are vector spaces and therefore have bases.  Lie groups are in general not vector spaces (in particular $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is not naturally a vector space) so it does not make sense to talk about a basis of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$.

As to whether you can specify an isomorphism $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C) \to \mathrm O_2(\mathbb C)$, you can't.  Those groups are not isomorphic Lie groups.  For example, $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is connected and $\mathrm O_2(\mathbb C)$ is not.

Comment: Yes, I made a wrong choice of words which was pointed out to me in the comment to the question.

Comment: I edited my question according to Ben Blum-Smith's comment.

Comment: I am upvoting: although I did not confuse algebra and groups I wasn't too clear about Lie groups either. I do not accept your answer because I still don't know whether what I outlined in the question is correct and if it is, if I can do it.

Comment: @learner: I've added an answer to whether you can do as you say.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Does this mean my idea doesn't work or can I instead use just a group homo $SL_2(\mathbb C)\to O(3,\mathbb C)$ and take the derivative of that to get a Lie algebra iso?

Comment: If those Lie algebras are isomorphic then there exists an isomorphism and by the theorem you've stated it's the derivative of some group homomorphism.  So yes, looking for a group homomorphism will work.

Comment: Since the lie algebra of $SL_2$ is 3-dimensional, I bet you will get the homomorphism you want by considering the action of $SL_2$ by conjugation on its Lie algebra. In other words, there is a group homomorphism $SL_2\rightarrow GL_3$, gotten by identifying $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ with $\mathbb{C}^3$ (via some choice of a basis), and sending a matrix $A\in SL_2$ to whatever matrix describes (in terms of the coordinates of $A$) the action $X\mapsto AXA^{-1}$ on matrices $X\in\mathfrak{sl}_2$ (described in terms of your chosen basis). I bet if you pick the basis right, the image will be in $O_3$.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is true. The action of $SL_2$ on its lie algebra preserves the Killing form, so the image of the homomorphism describing this action will land in $O_3$ (for any basis orthonormal with respect to the Killing form). This will give an explicit description of the required group homomorphism. @learner, if you'd like me to write this up as an answer, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{gl}_2$ (by definition -- $\text{tr}$ being a Lie algebra homomorphism). Now $t(X,Y) = \text{tr}(XY)$ is easily seen to be a nondegenerate invariant bilinear form for $\mathfrak{gl}_2$ and clearly $\mathfrak{gl}_2 = \mathbb C.I_2 \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ is an orthogonal direct sum for $t$, so that $t$ restricts to give a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. Thus the adjoint representation $(\mathfrak{sl}_2, \text{ad})$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ given by $\text{ad}(X)(Y) = [X,Y]$ gives an injective homomorphism $\text{ad}\colon \mathfrak{sl}_2\to \mathfrak{so}_{3}(\mathbb C)$, where if $\{e,f,h\}$ denote the standard "$\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple" basis of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, that is $e= E_{12}, f = E_{21}$ and $h = E_{11}-E_{22}$, then the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb C)$ is the Lie algebra for which the quadratic form $q(\alpha.h + \beta.e +\gamma) = 2(\alpha^2 +\beta\gamma)$. Since $\mathfrak{so}_3$ is $3$-dimensional and $\text{ad}$ is injective, it follows that $\text{ad}$ is an isomorphism.

If you use the Killing form, you obtain essentially the same construction, because the Killing form $\kappa$ is simply a multiple of the form $t$.

Finally, this homomorphism specialises to give an isomorphism between  $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathfrak{so_3}(2,1)$, since it is easy to check that the form $t$, over the reals, has signature $(2,1)$